# to String value

Tags: java, object-to-string

Hello all I am new in java.Please help me

I have following code

```
package sun.mun.fun;

import inship.InShipException;
import inship.PackageDetail;
import inship.Uspsrates;
import inship.UspsratesAboutPropertyEditor;
import inship.UspsratesBeanInfo;
import inship.UspsratesRequestedServicePropertyEditor;

public class Usps {


    public Uspsrates getRate()  {
        Uspsrates rate = new Uspsrates();

        try {
            rate.getUSPSAccount().setServer(rate.toString());
            rate.getUSPSAccount().setServer("http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll");  
            rate.getUSPSAccount().setUserId("747THEFI1034");
            rate.getUSPSAccount().setPassword("510QU40FX616");
            rate.getSenderAddress().setZipCode("27502");
            rate.getRecipientAddress().setZipCode("20770");
            rate.getPackages().add(new PackageDetail());
            rate.getPackages().item(0).setWeight("1");
            rate.getPackages().item(0).setLength(Integer.parseInt("5"));
            rate.getPackages().item(0).setWidth(Integer.parseInt("5"));
            rate.getPackages().item(0).setHeight(Integer.parseInt("5"));    
            rate.getPackages().item(0).setGirth((2 * rate.getPackages().item(0).getLength()) + (2 * rate.getPackages().item(0).getWidth()));
            rate.getPackages().item(0).setSize(Integer.parseInt("0"));
            rate.getPackages().item(0).setPackagingType(inship.PackageDetail.ptNone);
            rate.setRequestedService(inship.Uspsrates.stUnspecified);
            rate.getRates();

        } catch (InShipException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return rate;


    }


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Usps [getRate()=" + getRate() + "]";
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Usps u = new Usps();

    System.out.println(u.getRate().toString());


}


}
```

and when I run this it gives this output

> inship.Uspsrates@16672d6

I don't want this value.I want this in string.What should i do any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: -1 Overload `toString` but not `hashCode` is bad practice. Inherited Classes will always give `Usps` in `toString`, even if the inherited class has a different class-name.

Comment: i think you should simply System.out.println(u.toString()); to get the desired output - but look at @PeterRader hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Uspsrates`  class should override `toString()` method and should return a `String` with the details  you want.If you  simply print an Object,the compiler converts it into `Object.toString()` and returns a String in the following format `ClassName@Hashcode`

Check the documentation for the Object's to String method [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

Answer (score 1):

Move your `toString()` implementation to your `Uspsrates` object.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Usps [getRate()=" + getRate() + "]";
}
```

Because your `getRate()` method returns a `Uspsrates` not `Usps`

Comment: Been trying to work out where the downvote comes from. This answer is technically correct, but fails to describe how/why this will fix the problem.

Comment: Edited it to explain the solution.

Comment: How do you know `Uspsrates` has a `getRate()` method?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav: It did deserve the down-vote when it was first posted, but not now. It has been since removed.

Comment: @bcsb1001, no I don't. What I said is that his `getRate()` method returns `Uspsrates` not `Usps`.

Comment: @all chill guys..Life is precious not to waste time on votes.Leave it to the politicians :P

Answer (score 0):

`gives this output inship.Uspsrates@16672d6`

what else do you expect it should give you

Your `toString()` is inside the `Usps` class but your `getRate()` method returns an Object of type `Uspsrates`

When you are doing this

```
System.out.println(u.getRate().toString());
```

It is just printing the hash of the object returned by `getRate()`

*How to fix this?*

Just add a toString() inside your `Uspsrates` class